# Display element just once only on scrolling up or down when in viewport (waypoints)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints, waypoint

I'm using jquery waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs) to check if an element is the view of the browser

I want to display element just once only on scrolling up or down when in viewport ...here the js

```
var inview = new Waypoint.Inview({
element: $('#waypoint')[0],
enter: function(direction) {
if (direction === 'down') {

    setTimeout(function() {
 $('#first').hide('fast');
 }, 500); // <-- time in milliseconds



 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#second').fadeIn("fast");;
  }, 500); // <-- time in milliseconds

   }
if (direction === 'up') {

    setTimeout(function() {
 $('#first').hide('fast');
 }, 500); // <-- time in milliseconds



 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#second').fadeIn("fast");;
  }, 500); // <-- time in milliseconds

   }



    }
  })
```

This code is working perfectly when scrolling is down but not working when scrolling is up.

I want when detect position is down run only the down function and when detect the position is up run only the function up

Comment: Well you made everything for direction === 'down' ... Now do for direction up...

Comment: not working for direction ==='up' ....